# Aggregate query , using array aggregate function but one of the value in separated column

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql I am having difficulty creating aggregate query with array agreggate value but want to make one of the value
put in its own column.

I have a language translation table something like this
let's called it *component_translation*

```
id, component_code, language_code, name
1   abc             en             tyre
2   abc             de             reifen
3   abc             es             llanta
4   def             en             rim
5   def             de             felge
```

English language always exist in the table, but other languages not always.
I want to query it  to be like this:

```
component_code | english_name | other_names
abc            | tyre | {reifen,llanta}
def            | rim  | {felge}
```

I'm stuck , all  I can do  now is this:

```
select component_code, 
array_agg(name::text) as all_name,
from component_translation
group by  component_code
```

which is not what I want.

Any clue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation using the `FILTER` clause for it:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4119bfc69192a5fa4f57da0f21db7f18)

```
SELECT
    component_code, 
    MAX(name) FILTER (WHERE language_code = 'en') as en_name,
    ARRAY_AGG(name) FILTER (WHERE language_code != 'en') as all_name
FROM component_translation
GROUP BY component_code
```

Comment: `filter` is part of the SQL standard as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need conditional aggregations as follows:

```
select component_code, 
       max(case when language_code = 'en' then name::text end) as en_name,
array_agg(case when language_code <> 'en' then name::text end) as all_name,
from component_translation
group by  component_code
```

You can also use `FILTER` for conditional aggregation.

Comment: The array contains NULL values in that case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8c7d809bc0373f418c1d895515f91840

Answer (score 1):

I have considered that there will only be one English name for each component_code, array_agg will return null in the array for english names and i have used array_remove to get rid of those.

```
select component_code, 
       max(case when language_code = 'en' then name::text end) as englisth_name,
array_remove(array_agg(case when language_code <> 'en' then name::text end),NULL) as other_names
from component_translation
group by  component_code
order by component_code
```

**Output:**

[image]